# Robot framework solution to allow browser notification

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Could anyone help me how to automate the allow notifications(not alert) actions from a site?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HQ8X.jpg)

I tryed this code but it only kind of minimize the window and don't take the allow action:

```
${options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys
Call Method ${options} add_argument --disable-notifications
Call Method ${options} add_argument --disable-infobars
Call Method ${options} add_argument start-maximized
Call Method ${options} add_argument --disable-extensions
${driver}= Create Webdriver Chrome options=${options}
```

Answer (score 0):

***For Chrome***

```
//Create a map to store  preferences 
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

//add key and value to map as follow to switch off browser notification
//Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);

//Create an instance of ChromeOptions 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

// set ExperimentalOption - prefs 
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

//Now Pass ChromeOptions instance to ChromeDriver Constructor to initialize chrome driver which will switch off this browser notification on the chrome browser
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: @Renatoars8,  Please accept the answer if the this has resolved your issue.